# Nova instance missing after reboot

Tags: openstack

I had an instance today which appeared to be stuck booting, I did a hard reboot and then the hypervisor lost power.  After turning back on the instance was still in hard reboot, however it appears stuck, and now missing.

```
[root@hv11 ~(keystone_admin)]# nova list | grep HARD_REBOOT
| fbc4e86a-c97a-4556-a0cc-9891558bc728 | instance name      | HARD_REBOOT | rebooting_hard | Running     | tenant=xxxx, xxxx |
```

I've searched through `virsh list` and no instances shown in there match up with this one, it also appears that there's no trace of it in `/var/lib/nova/instances/`.  Did the data just disappear?

I've tried resetting the state on the instance with no luck.

```
[root@hv11 ~(keystone_admin)]# nova reset-state --active fbc4e86a-c97a-4556-a0cc-9891558bc728
Reset state for server fbc4e86a-c97a-4556-a0cc-9891558bc728 failed: Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:os-admin-actions:reset_state to be performed. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-ee5ffac6-ef04-4072-960a-cc9863584c24)
ERROR (CommandError): Unable to reset the state for the specified server(s).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the cause was a host migration scheduled a month ago went off un-expectantly with the hard reboot.  The migration failed though because the compute host it was migrating too was decommed since then.  All data lost, bummer.  This was on Openstack Liberty.